# Get time sensitive specific data from SQL db in .Net

Tags: .net, sql, linq, api, datetime

I need help to change one of my API's methods.
I have DB with few events like this:

```
EventName: Event 1 EventDate: 2013-08-15 00:00:00:00.000 isActive: true

EventName: Event 2 EventDate: 2013-08-16 00:00:00:00.000 isActive: true

EventName: Event 3 EventDate: 2013-08-17 00:00:00:00.000 isActive: true
```

Now, I have this method:

```
public IQueryable<Event> allActiveAndToday(){
     return this.Where(e => e.IsActive)
}
```

This method return all the events above and I want to change it to return only events in the same date between 8:00AM & 8:00AM next day.

For example:

- if the method get called at 7:00AM at 08/16/2013 the result will be `Event 1`.
- if the method get called at 9:00AM at 08/16/2013 the result will be `Event 2`.
- if the method get called at 7:00AM at 08/17/2013 the result will be `Event 2`.
- if the method get called at 9:00AM at 08/17/2013 the result will be `Event 3`.

let say that it's like the day start & end in 8:00AM every day..

I can't find a way to do it, because i'm not familiar with the options and context I have in .net.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should do it:

```
public IQueryable<Event> allActiveAndToday(){
    DateTime currentDt = DateTime.Now;
    DateTime start = new DateTime(currentDt.Year, currentDt.Month, currentDt.Day, 8, 0, 0);
    DateTime end = start.AddDays(1);

    // This will check if the the current date/time falls between 8AM and 8AM (the following day)
    // If not then set the currentDt to yesterday's date.
    if (!(currentDt >= start && currentDt <= end))
    {
        currentDt = currentDt.AddDays(-1);
    }

    // Then do your query here...
    var events = this.Where(x => x.IsActive && x.EventDate.Date == currentDt.Date).ToList();

    return events;
}
```

Comment: So great !! checking your answer and coming back to mark it ! Thanks!

Comment: This is mostly a good answer, but you may want to consider excluding the end date:  `currentDt < end` since that is usually implied with these sort of ranges.  Also, if this is a web application, you haven't addressed the problem of "whose now is it?".  Using `DateTime.Now` will give you the *server's* time.  That might not be the user's time at all.

Comment: i think that this is my problem because im nor getting the result i wanted i will check it again and let you now.